# Shape of design matrix in linear regression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning, linear-regression

For a linear regression problem (Bishop book 3.1 pp. 138-143), the basis function is calculated as such:

$$\boldsymbol{\phi}_i = (\phi_0(\mathbf{x}_N), \phi_1(\mathbf{x}_N), ..., \phi_M(\mathbf{x}_N) )^{T} $$

that is applied to a data point $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^D$ and with i = {1, 2, ..., N} and N the total number of samples.

I am trying to understand why the following expression $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \boldsymbol{\phi}_i \boldsymbol{\phi}_i^{T} = \boldsymbol{\Phi}^{T} \boldsymbol{\Phi}$ is true,

with $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ to be the design matrix which is equal to:

$$\left[\begin{array}{l} \phi_0(\mathbf{x}_1) &\phi_1(\mathbf{x}_1) & \cdots & \phi_{M-1}(\mathbf{x}_1)\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ \phi_0(\mathbf{x}_N) &\phi_1(\mathbf{x}_N) & \cdots & \phi_{M-1}(\mathbf{x}_N)\end{array}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$$

Any intuition why this holds?

Comment: Do you have the correct expression? Should that perhaps be $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \boldsymbol{\phi}_i \boldsymbol{\phi}_i^{T} = \boldsymbol{\Phi} \boldsymbol{\Phi}^T$?

Comment: This is what Bishop's books states, also note that I am making use of the denominator notation so a vector $\boldsymbol \phi$ is a column vector. However, do you have proof for your expression?

Comment: Ok I think I was missing a transpose in the \phi vector!

Comment: When I see strange commutativity I check if something got defined as a transpose, $a^Tb=b^Ta$, Cramer's rule, duel space shenanigans, or a typo. They seem to the usual culprits. When I see a sum of outer products I envision the projection onto a larger subspace decomposed into it's one dimensional projections which could be relevant here too. Like if I project $(x,y,z)$ onto $(x,y,0)$ I can write this as $(x,y,0) =(x,0,0)+(0,y,0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you mean $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\phi_{i}^{T}\phi_{i}=\Phi\Phi^{T}$. Let $$\phi_{i}:=\phi(x_{i})=\left(\phi_{0}(x_{i}),\phi_{1}(x_{i}),\ldots,\phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\right)^{T}$$ and

$$\Phi=\left(
 \begin{array}{cccc}
\phi_{0}(x_{1}) & \phi_{1}(x_{1}) & \ldots & \phi_{M-1}(x_{1})\\
\phi_{0}(x_{2}) & \phi_{1}(x_{2}) & \ldots & \phi_{M-1}(x_{2})\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
\phi_{0}(x_{N}) & \phi_{1}(x_{N}) & \ldots & \phi_{M-1}(x_{N})\\
\end{array}
 \right)
$$
Then the result follows simply by calculation of $\Phi^{T}\Phi$.

$$\Phi^{T}\Phi=\left(
 \begin{array}{cccc}
\phi_{0}(x_{1}) & \phi_{0}(x_{2}) & \ldots & \phi_{0}(x_{N})\\
\phi_{1}(x_{1}) & \phi_{1}(x_{2}) & \ldots & \phi_{1}(x_{N})\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
\phi_{M-1}(x_{1}) & \phi_{M-1}(x_{2}) & \ldots & \phi_{M-1}(x_{N})\\
\end{array}
 \right)
\left(
 \begin{array}{cccc}
\phi_{0}(x_{1}) & \phi_{1}(x_{1}) & \ldots & \phi_{M-1}(x_{1})\\
\phi_{0}(x_{2}) & \phi_{1}(x_{2}) & \ldots & \phi_{M-1}(x_{2})\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
\phi_{0}(x_{N}) & \phi_{1}(x_{N}) & \ldots & \phi_{M-1}(x_{N})\\
\end{array}
 \right)$$

$$=
\left(
 \begin{array}{cccc}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \phi_{0}(x_{i})\phi_{0}(x_{i}) & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \phi_{0}(x_{i})\phi_{1}(x_{i}) & \ldots & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \phi_{0}(x_{i})\phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\\
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \phi_{1}(x_{i})\phi_{0}(x_{i}) & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \phi_{1}(x_{i})\phi_{1}(x_{i}) & \ldots & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \phi_{1}(x_{i})\phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\\\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\phi_{0}(x_{i}) & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\phi_{1}(x_{i}) & \ldots & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\\
\end{array}
 \right)\\
=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}
\left(
 \begin{array}{cccc}
\phi_{0}(x_{i})\phi_{0}(x_{i}) &  \phi_{0}(x_{i})\phi_{1}(x_{i}) & \ldots &  \phi_{0}(x_{i})\phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\\
 \phi_{1}(x_{i})\phi_{0}(x_{i}) &  \phi_{1}(x_{i})\phi_{1}(x_{i}) & \ldots & \phi_{1}(x_{i})\phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
 \phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\phi_{0}(x_{i}) &  \phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\phi_{1}(x_{i}) & \ldots &  \phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\phi_{M-1}(x_{i})\\
\end{array}
 \right)\\
=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\phi_{i}^{T}\phi_{i}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any definition for $\phi_i$ as you wrote.
[image]